# Absolute path in IMG SRC does not display image

Tags: php, html, image, src, absolute-path

I am using my own server running Windows Server 2008 and IIS v7.5. The OS is on the c: drive along with the website. I have a number of photos and videos with associated text files which are currently also on the c: drive (see simplified structure below) which I wish to move to a larger d: drive on the same server.

OS(C:)
- inetpub
--- wwwroot
----- albums
------- index.html
------- xxx.php
------- etc
------- info
---------- textfile1.txt
---------- textfile2.txt
---------- etc
------- photos
---------- photo1.jpg
---------- photo2.jpg
---------- etc

I currently output the text files and photos using a 'for' loop within PHP which simplified look like:

include 'info/textfile1.txt';
img src = 'photos/photo1.jpg' alt = "photo1.jpg" width="200px"

which both work.

Prior to moving the files to the d: drive I have expanded these to absolute pathnames:

include 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/albums/info/textfile1.txt';
which works, and

img src = 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/albums/photos/photo1.jpg' alt = "photo1.jpg" width="200px"

which does not work (just displays the 'alt' text).

To be absolutely clear, all of these files are on the server.

So,
1.  Why doesn't the img src with full pathname work and how do I get it to work?
2.  Is there any security (or other) risk with this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will never work
"img src" works in client's browser, which doesn't have access to the server's directory structure and files below the c:/inetpub/wwwroot directory.
Absolute paths in "img src" can only be "http://domain.com/folder/file.ext", like that

Comment: Many thanks @Oleg Dubas, I now understand that and using your example works just fine.  My real problem now is that I want to display photos from my larger d: drive which I guess I can't reference using the "http://domain.com/folder/file.ext" format as this points to folders below the wwwroot folder on the c: drive.  How would I do that, assuming it is possible?

Comment: It's just not possible :) The only way to do it is to write a server script which will physically read the file from drive D: (which is accessible to that script) and throw it to the browser output. It's a very simple script, for example: <?php header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); readfile('D:/photo.jpg'); ?>

Comment: Brilliant! Many thanks @Oleg Dubas, I now have this working using img src='load-image.php?$image.jpg' type structure with file exists checks; header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); readfile('D:/photo.jpg'); etc in the load-image.php file and its working great.

Comment: My next challenge will be to do the same for my video files, hopefully using the same or similar technique (?) ... but that's for another day. (There was a mistype in my previous comment - I meant img src='load-image.php?image=$photo' but I'm sure you knew that). Thanks again.